# same timestamp descending condition in php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have given some timestamp condition descending , but if all timestamp are equals then descending condition is not working . It's returning the first row only, I need the last row.

below is code

```html
         $this->db->like("time_stamp",$_POST['date'],"after");
         $this->db->order_by("time_stamp DESC");
         $this->db->limit("1");
         $query5= $this->db->get_where("report",array("student_id" => $student_id));
```

Please check table screenshot.

[image]

I need the last row ,not the first .
here timestamp is same , so its not coming .

is there any way to do it ??

Comment: You are asking to sort timestamps which are the same - when it gets this is orders them by ID usually. You can sort by multiple fields: first sort by timestamp as you are, *then* sort by insert ID with the largest first. This will overcome the issue when the timestamps are identical.

Comment: I dont need id sort.I want to use only timestamp.  @samiles

Comment: Right, but you want the last one? How can you do that if the timestamps are identical? The only way is to sort by something else - first the timestamps, then, *if you have multiple identical timestamps*, sort by inserted ID. That is only way to tell which order they were inserted. How else could you tell which timestamp you want?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this is add another order_by condition based on your PK for the table, e.g.

```
$this->db->order_by('time_stamp DESC, id DESC');
```

Can you do this, in your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do further sorting when the data is exactly the same. What you can do is set a 2nd criteria when data is the same, it'll continue to the second criteria for ordering.

Normally you use your ID value. If you want the latest added you can use the below.

```
 $this->db->order_by("time_stamp DESC");
 $this->db->order_by("id DESC"); // this is the new line in your code
```

If you want the earlier added you can use the below code.

```
$this->db->order_by("time_stamp DESC");
$this->db->order_by("id"); // by default is ASC
```

Another way is like this in 1 row

```
$this->db->order_by("time_stamp DESC, id DESC");
```